Looking for suggestions on how to implement automated E2E testing of an embedded Shopify App - tests are triggering Cloudflare Turnstile
Looking for suggestions on how to implement end-to-end automated testing of an embedded Shopify App (that can only be accessed through Shopify Admin).
We have written a set of Playwright tests to smoke test basic app functionality against regressions, etc. Tests run fine from a local terminal. When run from CI (GitHub Actions) they trigger Cloudflare Turnstile (bot detection) when attempting to load any Shopify Admin URL. We aren't able to get past that and run any of our tests.
We have no control over Shopify Admin and their Cloudflare Turnstile implementation (so can't pass test keys), and Shopify's support insists that Turnstile can not be controlled or disabled through Shopify.
Has anybody had any luck implementing automated E2E testing of an embedded Shopify app with any framework?
